# kubernetes RBAC role verbs to exec to pod

Tags: kubernetes

I my 1.9 cluster created this deployment role for the dev user. Deployment works as expected. Now I want to give exec and logs access to developer. What role I need to add for exec to the pod?

```
kind: Role
name: deployment-manager
  rules:
  - apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
    resources: ["deployments", "replicasets", "pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

Error message:

```
kubectl exec nginx -it -- sh  

Error from server (Forbidden): pods "nginx" is forbidden: User "dev" cannot create pods/exec in the namespace "dev"
```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 88, accepted):

The [RBAC docs say that](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources)

> Most resources are represented by a string representation of their name, such as “pods”, just as it appears in the URL for the relevant API endpoint. However, some Kubernetes APIs involve a “subresource”, such as the logs for a pod. [...] To represent this in an RBAC role, use a slash to delimit the resource and subresource.

To allow a subject to read both pods and pod logs, and be able to exec into the pod, you would write:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-and-pod-logs-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods", "pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["create"]
```

Some client libraries may do an http GET to negotiate a websocket first, which would require the "get" verb. kubectl sends an http POST instead, that's why it requires the "create" verb in that case.

Comment: I had to add the verb `"get"` to my `pods/exec` section as well since the client library I'm using is doing an http `GET` to negotiate a websocket first. Using kubectl it sends an http `POST` and requires the `"create"` verb in that case. It may be worth updating this example to include the `"get"` verb.

Comment: Added a note about it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The official Python library (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/) uses WebSockets ( https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/issues/58 ), which sends a GET request even if you use `connect_post_namespaced_pod_exec` instead of `connect_get_namespaced_pod_exec`. `Kubectl` uses SPDY instead of websockets and is able to send a POST request directly.